# Atlassian Connect Express: Credentials rejected at connect-ace.atlassian.net

Tags: jira, atlassian-connect

I'm evaluating atlassian-connect-express and just created an app
boilerplate with "atlassian-connect new", and then deployed it via ngrok
to my Jira dev account.

That works fine, but when I try to use the file "credentials.json" with
my account data, the plug starts with the error message:

> Failed to register with host https‍://michael%40...:[My
>   password]@connect-ace.atlassian.net (401)
>   Add-on not registered; no compatible hosts detected

I get a similar message when I go to the url connect-ace.atlassian.net

Here my atlassian-connect.json

```
{
    "key": "my-add-on",
    "name": "Ping Pong",
    "description": "My very first add-on",
    "vendor": {
        "name": "Angry Nerds",
        "url": "https://www.atlassian.com/angrynerds"
    },
    "baseUrl": "https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io",
    "links": {
        "self": "https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json",
        "homepage": "https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "jwt"
    },
    "lifecycle": {
        "installed": "/installed"
    },
    "scopes": [
        "READ"
    ],
    "modules": {
        "generalPages": [
            {
                "key": "hello-world-page-jira",
                "location": "system.top.navigation.bar",
                "name": {
                    "value": "Hello World"
                },
                "url": "/hello-world",
                "conditions": [{
                    "condition": "user_is_logged_in"
                }]
            },
            {
                "key": "hello-world-page-confluence",
                "location": "system.header/left",
                "name": {
                    "value": "Hello World"
                },
                "url": "/hello-world",
                "conditions": [{
                    "condition": "user_is_logged_in"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my credatials.json

```
{
    "hosts": {
        "connect-ace.atlassian.net": {
            "product": "jira",
            "username": "michael@---",
            "password": "---password---"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get my dev account working with connect-ace?

Comment: What password did you use? The password should be an API token created via their ID platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check:

1 - Check the if the credentials.json has correct values. host url should start with   **https://**. Password is the api token generated from [here](https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens).

```
{
    "hosts": {
        "https://<your atlassian site name>.atlassian.net": {
            "product": "jira",
            "username": "<jira user name>",
            "password": "<Token created from https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens>"
        }
    }
}
```

2- [Enable development mode](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/getting-started/) at Settings -> Apps -> Manage Apps -> Settings. (This is required if the app is not published in marketplace)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and this doesn't solve the issue for me. I can see in that the token is correct because it shows as used in the page where I generate it. I also checked that development mode is enabled probably 10 times by now.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a default from atlas-connect
[Print error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkFjq.jpg)

In atlasssian-connect.json 
**replace this :**

```
  "lifecycle": {
        "installed": "/installed"
    },
```

**for this:**

```
 "lifecycle": {
        "installed": "installed"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried spawning your own cloud instance and testing it there? If not yet, try creating one [here](https://www.atlassian.com/ondemand/signup/form?product=confluence.ondemand,jira-software.ondemand,jira-servicedesk.ondemand,jira-core.ondemand&developer=true). Once successfully registered, in your credentials.json, change "connect-ace" with your baseUrl/sitename and with the right credentials, it should automatically install it for you.